# TikZ: applying width to nodes programmatically, and 'Undefined control sequence pgf'

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, width

This is what I want to do: given two (horizontal) nodes, calculate the x distance between them, and produce a rectangular node with the same width as the x-distance between the nodes, placed below them.

I have tried the following code, reusing [Working with \pgfmathparse inside a path / calculations - Why is this let expression not working in TikZ (calculating a midpoint)? - TeX - LaTeX - Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/why-is-this-let-expression-not-working-in-tikz-calculating-a-midpoint/2212#2212):

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,chains,positioning,matrix,calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tt]
    \node (A1) [shape=circle,draw]              {A1};
    \node (A2) [shape=circle,draw,right=of A1]  {A2};

    % draw a rectangular node
    \draw let \p1 = (A1.west), \p2 = (A2.east) 
      in \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathparse{\x2 - \x1}
      }
        node[draw,right,below=of A1,text width=\pgfmathresult pt]{test};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This results with the image below:

[image]

Obviously - the box is not as wide as the distance between the A1 and A2 nodes (and neither has its right edge aligned with A1.west).

Then I wanted to try something similar to the code given in [Re: tikz: getting width of node programmatically](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-07/msg00997.html), which also uses `\pgfextra`, so I tried something like:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,chains,positioning,matrix,calc}
\newdimen{\mydim}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tt]
    \node (A1) [shape=circle,draw]              {A1};
    \node (A2) [shape=circle,draw,right=of A1]  {A2};

    % draw a rectangular node
    \draw let \p1 = (A1.west), \p2 = (A2.east) 
      in \pgfextra{
        \pgf@x=\n1
        \pgf@y=1cm
        \divide\pgf@x by \pgf@y
        \setlength{\mydim}{\pgf@x}      
      }
        node[draw,right,below=of A1,text width=\mydim pt]{test};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

... however, for that code, LaTeX seems to crash when it encounters `\pgf@x`, since the error message is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument>  \pgf 
                 @x=\n 1 \pgf @y=1cm \divide \pgf @x by \pgf @y \setlength {...
l.40      }

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The only reference I found to this was kind of error was in [pgfdeclareshape example not compilable - pgf-users](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.pgf.user/3577), where the recommendation is:

> Does it compile if you put \makeatletter before \pgfdeclareshape{...} 
>   and \makeatother after? (It is missing from the example in the manual, 
>   but I suspect it is necessary).

... however, I do not see how it would apply here - since the purpose of all this pgf use here, is just calculation (not actual drawing/rendering).

Well, thanks in advance for any pointers,
Cheers!

**EDIT:** Well, with a (sort of a) combo of the approaches above, I am starting to get somewhere:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,chains,positioning,matrix,calc}
\newdimen{\mydim}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tt]
    \node (A1) [shape=circle,draw]              {A1};
    \node (A2) [shape=circle,draw,right=of A1]  {A2};

    % draw a rectangular node
    \draw let \p1 = (A1.west), \p2 = (A2.east) 
      in \pgfextra{%
        \pgfmathparse{\x2 - \x1}
        \setlength{\mydim}{\pgfmathresult pt}       
      }
        node[draw,right,below=of A1.west,anchor=west,text width=\mydim]{test};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

... but it's still not good. By using `anchor=west`, now there is proper alignment; and by getting rid of `\pgf@x`, and using `\pgfmathresult` to set the `\mydim` length - the width looks somewhat better, but longer than expected, see image:

[image]

So the remaining questions now are:

- how do I get the correct width of the box - so its left edge aligns with A2's left edge?
- Why is this 'crash' on encountering `\pgf@x` in `\pgfextra` happening?

Thanks again,
Cheers!

Comment: Whenever there is an @ in a command name, you need `\makeatletter` before that, so the advice does apply (you should put the commands before and after the `\draw`.

Comment: excellent - thank you Caramdir! Just tried it out and it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the reason that your first example doesn't give you the right length is that `\pgfmathresult` is overwritten somewhere before it is applied to the option (also you forgot subtracting the `inner sep`, this is the reason for the incorrect length in your edit). However, the node is placed correctly below (A1), as the default node alignment is centering.

**First step**: fix the `\pgfmathresult`. The `\pgfmathparse` isn't really needed here, we can simply do the following (the default `inner sep` between the text and the border is 0.3333em, so we need to subtract twice that for the `text width`):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tt]
    \node (A1) [shape=circle,draw]              {A1};
    \node (A2) [shape=circle,draw,right=of A1]  {A2};

    % draw a rectangular node
    \draw let \p1 = (A1.west), \p2 = (A2.east) in 
          node[draw,right,below=of A1,text width={\x2-\x1-0.6666em}]{test};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: result of step one]

**Second step**: fix the alignment. The `right` option doesn't do anything, so we can simply delete it. By default, nodes are anchored at their center. Actually, for `below=of ..`, they are anchored at the north (center). So we have to set `anchor=north west` to have the node to the right. But then it is to the right of A1.center (concretely, `node distance` below A1.south). So we need to specify `below=of A1.south west`. Unfortunately, that doesn't quite work as A1 is bounded by a circle (so `south west` is on the circle and not as far west and south as we would like). A1.west is a first approximation:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tt]
    \node (A1) [shape=circle,draw]              {A1};
    \node (A2) [shape=circle,draw,right=of A1]  {A2};

    % draw a rectangular node
    \draw let \p1 = (A1.west), \p2 = (A2.east) in 
          node[draw,below={of A1.west},anchor=north west,text width={\x2-\x1-0.6666em}]{test};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: result of step 2.1]

This isn’t quite perfect, since the third node is a bit too high now. The `circle` shape doesn't provide the correct anchor, so we have to calculate its position (it’s easy: A1.west gives the correct x-coordinate and A1.south the correct y-coordinate). Also, let’s add `align=center` to center the text in the node:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tt]
    \node (A1) [shape=circle,draw]              {A1};
    \node (A2) [shape=circle,draw,right=of A1]  {A2};

    % draw a rectangular node
    \draw let 
            \p1 = (A1.west),
            \p2 = (A2.east),
            \p3 = (A1.south)
          in node [
            draw,
            below={of (\x1,\y3)},
            anchor=north west,
            text width={\x2-\x1-0.6666em},
            align=center
          ] {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: finished image]

---

To get your second example to compile, you need to add `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in the appropriate places. By default, @ is in class “other” and cannot be used in command names. However, it is typically used in internal commands that the user should not access. `\makeatletter` makes @ a ”letter”, so that it can be used in command names. See also [Why do LaTeX internal commands have an @ in them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/why-do-latex-internal-commands-have-an-in-them). However the code seems to have other problems too and adding `\makeatletter` merely changes the error. I'm not yet sufficiently familiar with the ways TeX and LaTeX handle dimensions and lengths to give you advice how that code should be corrected.

Comment: Wow - thanks a LOT, Caramdir - an awesome answer! Especially thanks for the step by step details of "below" and such - I have great difficulties keeping those in check.. Thanks again - cheers!  ... oh yes - and the 'inner sep'? It would have taken me AGES to get to that!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Caramdir, here is also a version with usage of `\pgf@x`; while `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` is necessary to get rid of the `! Undefined control sequence`, the OP code also needs to use a 'counter' instead of a 'dimension' so that some width scaling occurs at all.

The code below should build and generate an image - but its width will, this time, be somewhat *shorter* than the 'total' distance between A1 and A2:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,chains,positioning,matrix,calc}
\newdimen{\mydim}
\newcounter{counterOne}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tt]

    \node (A1) [shape=circle,draw]              {A1};
    \node (A2) [shape=circle,draw,right=of A1]  {A2};

    % draw a rectangular node
    \makeatletter
    \draw let \p1 = (A1.west), \p2 = (A2.east) 
      in let \n{width} = {\x2 - \x1}
        in \pgfextra{
        % \pgf@x=\n1 % ! Missing number, treated as zero. \tikz@cc@n@1
        % manual: "the \p, \x, and \y macros refer to the same logical point, while the \n macro has “its own namespace.”"
        \pgf@x=\n{width}
        \pgf@y=1cm
        \divide\pgf@x by \pgf@y
        \setcounter{counterOne}{\pgf@x}  % NOWORK: \setlength{\mydim}{\pgf@x}
      }
        node[draw,right,below=of A1.west,anchor=west,text width=\thecounterOne cm]{test};
    \makeatother

\end{tikzpicture}
```

... with resulting image:

[image: shorter width with \pgf@x and counter code]

Well, in any case, I'm glad this question got solved :)
Cheers!

Comment: Why don't you simply use `text width=\n{width}`? Assigning a length to a counter seems to round it down to the next integer. (also again, it should be `{\x2-\x1-0.6666em}` (or whatever `inner sep` you have).

Comment: Hi @Caramdir - heh, you're right :) The thing is, I was just so overwhelmed with this, I simply couldn't do any better, than to try and follow the original example, [Re: tikz: getting width of node programmatically](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-07/msg00997.html), as much to the letter (_I was writing that while I still haven't properly gone through your answer_)... Needless to say - your suggestion is much better (though I think I'll leave writing a more proper example for some other time).. Thanks again - cheers!