# Using predefined constants with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I can't seem to get definitions of constants working in TikZ. I looked at [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/why-is-this-let-expression-not-working-in-tikz-calculating-a-midpoint) question and that too did not work for me.  This example works, but not if the swap the `\coordinate` definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\PI}{3.14}

\newcommand{\ValueOf}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{PIE}}{3.14159}{}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{E}}{2.78}{}%
}

\begin{document}

    Value of -PIE is -\ValueOf{PIE}.\par
    Value of E is \ValueOf{E}.

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (PointA)  at (-\PI,-1);             % Only this works
    %\coordinate (PointA) at (-\ValueOf{PIE},-1); 
    %\coordinate (PointA) at (\pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{-\ValueOf{PIE}}},-1); 

    \draw (PointA) circle (1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In case it is related, the package versions I have are:

**pgfplots 2010/07/14 Version 1.4**
**pgf 2008/01/15 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.12)**

Comment: pgfplot is out of the problem

Comment: Also have a look at [Why is the ifthen package obsolete ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete)

Comment: Side remark: Both constants you define are built into pgfmath. Simply writing `\coordinate (PointA)  at (2*e-4,2/3*pi);` works as expected.

Comment: Yeah I saw the why ifthen is obsolete previously but obviously did not understand it. Also, I plan to use this to be able to return a lot more constants and need it outside of pgf as well. I will try to remember to not dumb down the problem too much from now on -- The PI and E were just examples to illustrate the problem.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression given for coordinates must expand to a number. The `\ifthenelse` seem not to do that. One solution would be to define `\ValueOf` in an expandable way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\PI}{3.14}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ValueOf}[1]{%
    \@ifundefined{ValueOf@#1}{%
    % Add your error handler
    }{%
    \@nameuse{ValueOf@#1}%
    }
}
\newcommand{\DefValueOf}[1]{%
    \@namedef{ValueOf@#1}%
}

\DefValueOf{PIE}{3.14159}
\DefValueOf{E}{2.78}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Value of -PIE is -\ValueOf{PIE}.\par
    Value of E is \ValueOf{E}.

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (PointA)  at (-\PI,-1);             % Only this works
    \coordinate (PointA) at (-\ValueOf{PIE},-1); 
    %\coordinate (PointA) at (\pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{-\ValueOf{PIE}}},-1); 

    \draw (PointA) circle (1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Personally I don't see your problem with having macro constants like `\PI`.

Comment: I added a missing “not” to your second sentence (I think it makes more sense now).

Comment: Thanks @Caramdir: It got deleted by accident in an early edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Luatex](http://luatex.org/) and constants of Lua.

```
\directlua{tex.print(math.pi)}
```

inserts 3.1415926535898 in your document.

Comment: Nice idea, if you use LuaTeX. I personally would go for a simple `\def\PI{3.1415926535898}`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly your code but a solution is :
Better it's to use xstring package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\PI}{PI} 
\newcommand{\EULER}{EULER} 
\newcommand{\ValueOf}[1]{  
\ifx \PI#1 3.14159 %
  \else 
    \ifx \EULER#1 2.71828 % 
      \else 1 %
    \fi
\fi}  

\begin{document}

    Value of -PI is -\ValueOf{\PI}.\par
    Value of E is \ValueOf{\EULER}. \par 
\vspace*{1cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (PointA) at (\ValueOf{\PI} ,-1); 
    \draw (PointA) circle (\ValueOf{\PI});
    \draw  circle (\ValueOf{\EULER});  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```