# Using node or draw circle in tikz-3dplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-3dplot

I am exploring the `tikz-3dplot` package for drawing objects in 3d and experienced a problem. I simply want to draw a circle and reference some of the points later, but I found there is a difference when using the `draw` command and using the `node` command:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{1}{70}{40}

\draw[-stealth,color=blue] (O) -- (P);

\node[draw, circle, radius=0.2] (cir) at (P) {};
\draw[red] (P) circle [radius=0.2];

\draw (cir.south) -- (cir.north);

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Why is the difference? I would like to use `node` as I can reference, for example, the south and north points for later use, probably projection. But using `node` doesn't provide the right shape (I want the red circle to be drawn with `node` so I can reference it). I don't understand why the `node` is not using the `tdplot_main_coords` coordinate system. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `node` almost always draws on the 2d canvas; it is not aware of the 3d coordinate system provided by `tdplot_main_coords`. If you want to refer to a particular point on a circle just hard-code the coordinate.

Comment: @Symbol1 The 3d library allows you to draw the node in any plane.

Comment: @marmot I wonder how `.south` etc works in that case.

Comment: @Symbol1 You can see that in the lower part of my answer. `.south` is equivalent to `.-90`. Of course, this is a circle in the xy plane, so `.south` is the point with the smallest y value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you draw the circle by default in the xy-plane. You can draw it in the screen coordinates to "synchronize" it with the node.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{1}{70}{40}

\draw[-stealth,color=blue] (O) -- (P);

\node[draw, circle, radius=0.2] (cir) at (P) {};
\draw[red,tdplot_screen_coords] (P) circle [radius=0.2];

\draw (cir.south) -- (cir.north);

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want instead the node been drawn in the `xy` plane, this can be done with the `3d` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{1}{70}{40}

\draw[-stealth,color=blue] (O) -- (P);

\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
    \node[draw, circle, radius=0.2] (cir) at (P) {};
\end{scope} 
\draw[red] (P) circle [radius=0.2];
\draw (cir.south) -- (cir.north);

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried `\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]`as in your answer but it doesn't work for me, instead I need `canvas is yx plane at z=0,transform shape` and the north and south flip. I am using Texlive 2017, is that time to update? And I am wondering why the size of the circle drawn by `node` and `draw` are different? Thanks.

Comment: @bingung Yes, there was a small bug in the older versions of the 3d library, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799. This bug has been fixed recently, so, yes, it is time to update.

Comment: @bingung I just saw I missed the second part of your question. Nodes have `inner sep`, so you could do `\node[draw, circle, minimum width=0.4cm,inner sep=0pt] (cir) at (P) {};` to get the same radius. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48538/121799) for more details.