# Drawing a point

Tags: tikz-pgf, points

How do I draw a simple point using the **tikz** package? I can draw a line, a square, a circle and more, but not sure how to draw a point.
I tried

```
\draw(0,0);
```

expecting it to plot a point, but that didn't work. 
Any help would be appreciated, thank you. :)

Comment: What shape should the point have?

Comment: @Johannes_B Say, I have a circle and want to show its center, using a point, nothing extraordinary really. Is that possible to do using the tikz package? :)

Comment: `\fill (0,0) circle[radius=0.5pt];`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Hey it worked! Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: A point has no dimensions ... You want to draw a circle around a point, which is different ....

Comment: Well, this is definitely a very clear instance of [RTFM](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (**R**ead **T**he **F**antastic **M**anual).

Comment: Also this one could help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48538/how-to-set-exact-radius-for-a-node

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  I prefer the method of CarLatex something like `\node[draw,circle,minimum size=1pt,inner sep=0pt,fill=blue!20] at (0,0){};`. Useful to scale a picture without getting big points (small).

Comment: @Johannes_B, the point should be stroked witch the same style as every path passed to the `\draw` command. I have the same problem: How to force the `\draw` command to stroke the sigle points, eg. by `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) (1,0)`. Here is my problem: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671327/how-to-mark-a-single-point-on-path?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @cfr But the node has also dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would like to use a node, in this way you can reference the point afterward.

What you need to set the exact radius is `inner sep=0pt`, as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48540/101651).

I'll show you the difference in this simple example. In the first circle, the center node has `inner sep=0pt`; in the second circle, the center node has the standard inner sep:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,circle, minimum size=3cm, inner sep=0pt] (A) {};
\node[draw,circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=1pt] (mycenter) at (A.center) {};
\node[draw,circle, minimum size=3cm, inner sep=0pt, below = of A] (B) {};
\node[draw,circle, fill=black, minimum width=1pt] (mycenter) at (B.center) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Prof. van Duck explained this feature in his article [The Morse code of TikZ](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121duck-tikz.pdf), see Section 3.1.

Comment: I think it's the fine method.  It's possible to scale the picture with this definition.