# How to mark a single point on path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

I would like to include to one path both lines and points. My problem is that `\draw` command does not <del>draw</del> stroke a point while a single set of coordinates follows it. I.e. `\draw (0,0);` gives no visible effect.

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\pgfkeys{
    /glow settings/.is family,
    /glow settings,
    layers/.store in=\opacitysteps,
    width/.store in=\glowwidth,
    color/.store in=\linecolor,
    default/.style={
        layers=20,
        width=6pt,
        color=black
    }
}
\newcommand\drawglow[2][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/glow settings,default,#1}
    \foreach \w in {1,...,\opacitysteps}{
        \pgfmathparse{10/\opacitysteps*(1-pow(\w/\opacitysteps,0.25))}
        \edef\layeropacity{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\glowwidth*\w/\opacitysteps}
        \edef\layerwidth{\pgfmathresult}
        \draw [opacity=\layeropacity,line width=\layerwidth,color=\linecolor] #2;
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
\drawglow[width=15mm]{(0,0) -- (1,1) (2,2) (0,1) -- (1,0) (0,1.3) (2,2.1)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Initially I tried to adapt [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434603/modifying-argument-in-macro) to obtain the string `(0,0) -- (1,1) (2,2) -- ++(0,0) (0,1) -- (1,0) (0,1.3) -- ++(0,0) (2,2.3) -- ++(0,0)`, but without success.

I would like to obtain the following result:

[image]

EDIT: I am thinking about the LaTeX solution - not individual adjustment of each object. So the same options should modify the stoking style of paths and points. In my question the argument passed to the macro has the uniform style - both for dots and lines. So let we fix it to be `(0,0) -- (1,1) (2,2) (0,1) -- (1,0) (0,1.3) (2,2.1)`.
I found a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520403/drawing-a-point), but in fact left unanswered.

Comment: From Wikipedia: _a point is a primitive notion that models an exact location in space, and has no length, width, or thickness._

Comment: @Paul Gaborit, that true. I should ask "How to mark a point passed to the \path?"

Answer (score 3):

#### Original answer: append `circle[radius=.1pt]` manually

In example below, single coordinates, which correspond to the first n-1 [`move-to` path operations](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#sec-14.1) in a chain of consecutive n `move-to`s (n >= 2), are one-by-one converted to small circles (`<coordinate> circle[radius=.1pt]`).

Other power tikz players may provide more advanced hence more automatic solutions using for example decorations and/or soft path manipulations supported by [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3).

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\pgfkeys{
    /glow settings/.is family,
    /glow settings,
    layers/.store in=\opacitysteps,
    width/.store in=\glowwidth,
    color/.store in=\linecolor,
    default/.style={
        layers=20,
        width=6pt,
        color=black
    }
}
\newcommand\drawglow[2][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/glow settings,default,#1}
    \foreach \w in {1,...,\opacitysteps}{
        \pgfmathparse{10/\opacitysteps*(1-pow(\w/\opacitysteps,0.25))}
        \edef\layeropacity{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\glowwidth*\w/\opacitysteps}
        \edef\layerwidth{\pgfmathresult}
        \draw[opacity=\layeropacity,line width=\layerwidth,color=\linecolor] #2;
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \drawglow[width=15mm]{
    (0,0) -- (1,1)
    (2,2) circle[radius=.1pt]
    (0,1) -- (1,0)
    (0,1.3) circle[radius=.1pt]
    (2,2.1) circle[radius=.1pt]
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Update, insert `circle[radius=.1pt]` automatically

Some tikz internals are patched to allow inserting arbitrary path operations between consecutive `move-to`s, including the position between final `move-to` and `;`.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shadows}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\pgfkeys{
    /glow settings/.is family,
    /glow settings,
    layers/.store in=\opacitysteps,
    width/.store in=\glowwidth,
    color/.store in=\linecolor,
    default/.style={
        layers=20,
        width=6pt,
        color=black
    }
}
\newcommand\drawglow[2][]{%
    \pgfkeys{/glow settings,default,#1}
    \foreach \w in {1,...,\opacitysteps}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro\layeropacity{10/\opacitysteps*(1-pow(\w/\opacitysteps,0.25))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\layerwidth{\glowwidth*\w/\opacitysteps}
%        \pgfwarning{line width=\layerwidth}
        \draw[opacity=\layeropacity,line width=\layerwidth,color=\linecolor] #2;
    }
}


\makeatletter
\def\mytikz@text@moveto{moveto}

\xpatchcmd\tikz@handle
  % relax the match pattern from `\tikz@resetexpandcount\pgfutil@next`
  % to `\tikz@resetexpandcount`, to gain backward compatibility
  {\tikz@resetexpandcount}
  {%
    \let\mytikz@pathop@last=\mytikz@pathop@current
    \let\mytikz@pathop@current=\pgfutil@empty
    % specially handle the case when the last path operation before ";" is moveto
    \ifx\pgfutil@next\tikz@finish
      \mytikz@drawcoord@prepare
        {\let\pgfutil@next=\mytikz@drawcoord@drawfinish}%
    \fi
    \tikz@resetexpandcount
  }
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\xpatchcmd\tikz@moveto
  {\tikz@scan@one@point{\tikz@@moveto}}
  {%
    \let\mytikz@pathop@current=\mytikz@text@moveto
    \def\pgfutil@next{\tikz@scan@one@point{\tikz@@moveto}}%
    \mytikz@drawcoord@prepare
      {\let\pgfutil@next=\mytikz@drawcoord@drawbetween}%
    \pgfutil@next
  }
  {}{\PatchFailed}

\def\mytikz@drawcoord@prepare#1{%
  \ifx\mytikz@pathop@last\mytikz@text@moveto
    \unless\ifx\mytikz@drawcoord@code\pgfutil@empty
      #1%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\def\mytikz@drawcoord@drawbetween{%
  \expandafter\tikz@scan@next@command\mytikz@drawcoord@code}
\def\mytikz@drawcoord@drawfinish{%
  \expandafter\tikz@scan@next@command\mytikz@drawcoord@code;}

% user interface
\tikzset{
  draw coordinate/.store in=\mytikz@drawcoord@code,
  draw coordinate=% init to an empty value
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \drawglow[width=15mm]{
    (0,0) -- (1,1) 
    (2,2)
    (0,1) -- (1,0)
    (0,1.3)
    (2,2.1)
  }
  \node[below=of current bounding box] {before};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \drawglow[width=15mm]{
    (0,0) -- (1,1)
    (2,2) circle[radius=.1pt]
    (0,1) -- (1,0)
    (0,1.3) circle[radius=.1pt]
    (2,2.1) circle[radius=.1pt]
  }
  \node[below=of current bounding box] {manual solution};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  line cap=round,
  line join=round,
  draw coordinate={circle[radius=.1pt]}
]
  \drawglow[width=15mm]{
    (0,0) -- (1,1) 
    (2,2)
    (0,1) -- (1,0)
    (0,1.3)
    (2,2.1)
  }
  \node[below=of current bounding box] {auto solution};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am looking for the solution which enables passing parameters in the uniform style. By several rearrangements of points joined by lines adding and removing `circle` commands seems to be not a good solution. I would like to convert each `(x,y)` into `(x,y) -- ++(0,0)` or - following your suggestion - into `(x,y) circle[radius=half of my line width]`. I tried to incorporate such a conversion **into my macro**, but without success.

Comment: @forrest Hi, I just appended a new, automatic solution.

Comment: I got the error: `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \PatchFailed`. Of course I looked for the command `\patchcmd` in the etoolbox package. But still I don't know, how to fix this problem.

Comment: @forrest Which pgf-tikz version do you use?

Comment: I have pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021)

Comment: What's the exact version of tikz? tikz released between texlive 2021 and 2022, thus texlive 2021 installations may have different pgf versions installed, depending on whether user manually updated packages or not. You can add `\listoffiles` in preamble, compile, and then find package versions near the end of log.

Comment: @forrest Also please try the revised example, in which the match patten is relaxed a little bit.