# tikz/foreach: Protect space after "iteration variable"

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, foreach

I try to draw some nodes in tikz, and as they are very simple I wanted to "shorten" this using a `\foreach` command:

```
\foreach \xnum in {1,2,3,4,5}
{
    \node at (X\xnum center) {$x_\xnum$};
}
```

You can insert this into any MWE with a `tikzpicture` environement which has
some nodes X1, X2, ... defined.
(In my case, this are rectangles, using this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47797/22276 )

The problem with this is, that the space after `\xnum` is not preserved, which
is why I get the following error on running pdflatex:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named X1center is known.
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does `\xnum\space` work?

Comment: Awesome, yes, it does! I tried with `\ ` and `~` and `\xnum{}`, none of them did it. But yours is perfect. Do want to write it as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `\space` to get a literal space.

The active character `~` does not only produce a space, it produces a non-breakable space, saved in the macro `\nobreakspace` that expands to `\leavevmode\nobreak\␣` (LaTeX).

The `\xnum{}` trick to end the macro does not work because TikZ performs at some point a `\csname pgf@sh@ma@#1\endcsname` (where `#1` is our coordinate/node name) and at that point `{}` will become their actual characters: `No shape named X1{} center is known`.

The macro `\␣` is not good for `csname` either:  *The control sequence `\␣` should not appear between `\csname` and `\endcsname`.* (Freely adapted from the original error message.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (X1 center) at (0,0);
\coordinate (X2 center) at (1,0);
\coordinate (X3 center) at (2,0);
\coordinate (X4 center) at (3,0);
\coordinate (X5 center) at (4,0);

\foreach \xnum in {1,2,3,4,5}
{
    \node at (X\xnum\space center) {$x_\xnum$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is another approach, which may be used in other circumstances (e.g., where the content of the holder macro `\xnum` is needed directly without expansion).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,loops}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (X1 center) at (0,0);
\coordinate (X2 center) at (1,0);
\coordinate (X3 center) at (2,0);
\coordinate (X4 center) at (3,0);
\coordinate (X5 center) at (4,0);

\newforeach \xnum in {1,...,5} {\node at (X#1 center) {$x_\xnum$};}

% Or
% \foreachfox {1,...,5} {\node at (X#1 center) {$x_#1$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```