# Why is the text of this node not vertically centered?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, positioning

Consider the example below. **Why is the text not vertically centered?**

How do I get this working? I want to get this working with a node assigned to a draw object, because else I need to modify my entire figure ;-)

[Credits for the fitting node goes to this post.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167825/connecting-line-calculations-with-fitting-node-in-3d-tikz)

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  fitting node/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    fill=none,
    draw=none,
    reset transform,
    fit={(\pgf@pathminx,\pgf@pathminy) (\pgf@pathmaxx,\pgf@pathmaxy)}
  },
  reset transform/.code={\pgftransformreset}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
  \draw [rounded corners=15pt] (0,-2.0) rectangle ++(13.5,1.0) node[fitting node] {\strut Test Title};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

nodes with `fit` option doesn't center the content (top images), so with your solution you can achieve this using `label` (middle image) or use standard node (bottom image):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  fitting node/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    fill=none,
    draw=none,
    reset transform,
    fit={(\pgf@pathminx,\pgf@pathminy) (\pgf@pathmaxx,\pgf@pathmaxy)}
  },
  reset transform/.code={\pgftransformreset}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
  \draw [rounded corners=15pt] (0,-2.0) rectangle ++(13.5,1.0) node[fitting node] {Test Title};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
  \draw [rounded corners=15pt] (0,-2.0) rectangle ++(13.5,1.0) 
        node[fitting node, label=center: Test Title]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
titlebox/.style args = {#1/#2}{%
        draw, rounded corners=15pt, ultra thick,
        text width=#1, minimum height=#2, align=center}
                ]
\node[titlebox=135mm/10mm] {Test Title};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```