# How to stack rows of nodes in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I am try to create a diagram similar to the following in Tikz:

[image]

I know how to create each individual row I think, I'm doing something similar to:

```
\tikzstyle{cell} = [rectangle, rounded corners=5pt, thick, draw, text width=0.65cm ]
\node [cell, text width=8.7cm] (n1) {Z};
```

I figured I could stack them with something like:

```
\node [cell, text width=8.7cm] (n1) [above=of n2]{Z};                                                                                 
\node [cell, text width=4.1cm] (n2) {X};                                                                                              
\node [cell, text width=4.1cm] (n3) [right=of n2] {Y};
```

but that doesn't stack them the way I want to. I've seen similar answers using stuff like "above right", etc. but those seem to place them diagonally instead of aligned like the picture above.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code complete adding `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that a `tikz` `matrix` and the `fit` library could help you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, matrix, shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{% use tikzset, not tikzstyle
    cell/.style={
        rectangle, rounded corners=5pt, thick, draw,
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[
            matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
            minimum width=2cm,
            column sep=4pt,
            row sep=10pt,
            text height=2ex,text depth=.25ex,
            minimum height=4ex
            ] (m) {
            & & & \\
            & & & \\
            |[cell]| A & |[cell]| B & |[cell]| C & |[cell]| D \\
        } ;
        \node[cell, fit=(m-2-1)(m-2-2), inner sep=0pt, label=center: X] {};
        \node[cell, fit=(m-2-3)(m-2-4), inner sep=0pt, label=center: Y] {};
        \node[cell, fit=(m-1-1)(m-1-4), inner sep=0pt, label=center: Z] {};        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Credits for the `label=center:` goes to [Why is the text of this node not vertically centered?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337145/why-is-the-text-of-this-node-not-vertically-centered).

Answer (score 5):

This is a variation from CarLaTeX solution. It uses a `matrix` for the bottom row, but upper rows are built with a `fit` node placed with `positioning` library.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, matrix, positioning, shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{% use tikzset, not tikzstyle
    cell/.style={
        minimum width=2cm,
        text height=2ex,text depth=.25ex,
        minimum height=4ex,
        rectangle, rounded corners=5pt, thick, draw,
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[
            matrix of nodes,
            nodes = {cell, align=center},
            column sep=4pt,
            ] (m) {
            A & B & C & D \\
        } ;
        \node[cell, fit=(m-1-1)(m-1-2), inner sep=0pt, label=center: X, above left = 10pt and 0pt of m-1-2.north east] (X) {};
        \node[cell, fit=(m-1-3)(m-1-4), inner sep=0pt, label=center: Y, above left = 10pt and 0pt of m-1-4.north east] (Y) {};
        \node[cell, fit=(X)(Y), inner sep=0pt, label=center: Z, above left = 10pt and 0pt of Y.north east] {};        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Following solution uses a `tcbraster` from `tcolorbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{enhanced, fontupper=\bfseries, notitle, halign=center, valign=center}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[%
    raster width=10cm,
    raster equal height=rows, 
    raster columns=4,
    raster equal height,
    raster every box/.style={height=4ex},
    raster column skip=10pt,
    raster row skip=4pt,
    colback=white]
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=4] Z
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2] X
\tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2] Y
\tcbitem A
\tcbitem B
\tcbitem C
\tcbitem D
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oo interesting, I did not know about the raster package, thanks!

Comment: The tcolobox raster is a very good idea! Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

With nested loops, no TikZ `matrix`, nor any TikZ library.

I use the nice `label=center:#1` trick suggested by Carla.

It is certainly possible to manage both node length and coordinates `xscale` better, but I don't know how off the top of my head.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
{
  cell/.style=
  {
    rectangle,
    rounded corners=5pt,
    thick,
    draw,
    anchor=west,
    inner xsep=-2pt,
    minimum height=.7cm,
  }
}
\def\xScale{7cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\xScale]
  \foreach \k/\v in {0/{0/Z},1/{0/X,1/Y},2/{0/A,1/B,2/C,3/D}}
  {
    \foreach \kk/\vv in \v
    {
        \node 
        [
          cell,
          text width=1/2^\k * \xScale,
          label=center:\vv,
        ]
        at (\kk/2^\k,-\k)
        {};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah interesting use of for loops, speaks to the programmer side of me :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

as `forest` tree ... (adopted example from its documentation, page 29):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\forestset{box/.style={
  draw, rounded corners, minimum width=12mm,
  no edge,
  l=0, l sep=1mm,
  s=0, s sep=1mm,
  calign=first, anchor=base west,
  % content format={\strut\forestoption{content}},
  if n children=0{}{
    after packing node={
      minimum width/.pgfmath=
        {s("!l")+max_x("!l")-s("!1")-min_x("!1")},
      for children/.wrap pgfmath arg={s+={##1}}{0},
      typeset node}}}}
\begin{forest} for tree={box}
[Z
  [X
    [A][B]
  ]
  [Y
    [C]
    [D]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's pretty interesting, the way you can lay out the nodes in a quasi-WYSIWYG style is neat. Thanks!