# How can I add a node on top of a rectangle path?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I add a node on top of a rectangle path ?

```
\path[draw] (upperleft) rectangle (lowerright) node[???] {Top};
```

I am aware of the `midway` parameter that I can use, but this locates my Top label on the middle of the rectangle and not at top

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47704/how-to-establish-node-anchor-like-points-on-a-tikz-rectangle-path-is-there-a?rq=1 solves your problem. Or you could maybe use (this is untested) `\path (lowerright |- upperleft) -- (upperleft) node[midway] {top};`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility, although not very TikZ-idiomatic, is to combine your `\path` command with  Torbjørn's suggestion into a macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\namedrectangle[3][]{%
  \path[draw] (#2) rectangle (#3);
  \path (#3 |- #2) -- (#2) node[midway,above] {#1};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (upperleft) at (0,1);
\coordinate (lowerright) at (2,0);
\namedrectangle[Named rectangle]{upperleft}{lowerright}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option. If you know `corners coordinates` use `fit` library to draw the rectangle while the text is added with `label`. You can use `named` coordinates or just numerical ones. In this last case include coordinates list inside brackets.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red] (0,1) circle[radius=1pt] coordinate (upperleft);
\fill[red]  (2,0) circle[radius=1pt] coordinate (lowerright);
\node[draw, fit=(upperleft) (lowerright), inner sep=0pt, label={Named rectangle}] (rectangle) {};

\node[draw, fit={(3,0) (5,1.4)}, inner sep=0pt, label={[text width=2cm, align=center]Another named rectangle}
] (rectangle-b) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]