# Move / position tikz \draw plot in reference to a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

With this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47704/how-to-establish-node-anchor
  fitting node/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    fill=none,
    draw=none,
    reset transform,
    fit={(\pgf@pathminx,\pgf@pathminy) (\pgf@pathmaxx,\pgf@pathmaxy)}
  },
  reset transform/.code={\pgftransformreset},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% separately plot and box, else tikzedt don't show handles
\draw [black,thick] (1,3) rectangle (3.5,4)
  node[fitting node] (mynode) {};
%/* % also make tikzedt ignore (do not parse) this, plot kills all handles
\draw let \p1=(mynode) in
  [black, thick, domain=0:2.5,samples=50]
  plot (\x,{0.5*exp(-\x)*sin(1000*\x)});
%*/
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

... I get this:

[image: test.png]

I'm using `tikzedt`, and with that kind of syntax, it gives me handles to move the rectangle node around; I'd like to have the plot part inside it, so it moves along with the node.

Unfortunately, the `\draw` `plot` <s>crashes</s> gives entirely wrong results if it encounters `\x1` or `\y1` which would result from a `let` operation (e.g. as in `plot ({\x1+\x},{\y1+0.5*exp(-\x)*sin(1000*\x)});`).

So, how can I move the `\draw` `plot` inside the `(mynode)` (that is, make it's positioning in reference to `(mynode)`, instead of explicit)?

Answer (score 7):

Well, could have just used `shift`, wish I remembered earlier:

```
\draw let \p1=(mynode.west) in
  [black, thick, domain=0:2.5,samples=50,shift=(\p1)]
  plot ({\x},{0.5*exp(-\x)*sin(1000*\x)});
```

[image: test.png]