# drawing a neural network with bias with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know there are already some questions about drawing a neural network in here, but I'm trying to draw something like this : 
[image]

I have tried to apply some tutos and modified on some but this is my result, it's still so far away from the one above. 
[image]

and this is my code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
\begin{document}
\def\layersep{5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
 \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
 \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=25pt,inner sep=0pt]
 \tikzstyle{Cauche d'entrée}=[neuron, fill=gray!33];
 \tikzstyle{Cauche cachée}=[neuron, fill=gray!66];
 \tikzstyle{Cauche de sortie}=[neuron, fill=gray!99];
 \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=6em, text centered]

 % Draw the rectangle
\filldraw[fill=gray!33!white, draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (1.4,6);
 % Draw the input layer nodes
 \foreach \name / \y in {1,2,3,4,5,6}
 % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
 \node[Cauche d'entrée] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

 % Draw the hidden layer nodes
 \foreach \name / \y in {1,2,3,4}
 \path[yshift=0.5cm]
 node[Cauche cachée] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

 % Draw the output layer node
 \node[Cauche de sortie, pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Prévision}, right of=H-3] (O) {};

 % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
 % hidden layer.
 \foreach \source in {1,...,6}
 \foreach \dest in {1,2,3,4}
 \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

 % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
 \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
 \path (H-\source) edge (O);

 % Annotate the layers
 \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Cauche cachée};
 \node[annot,left of=hl] {Cauche d'entrée};
 \node[annot,right of=hl] {Cauche de sortie};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

As you can see, I'm so far away from what I want to draw. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: for start see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365404/  and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362663/  . welcome to tex.se

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX @Hamid701 ! Can you show us how yourself would draw the `variables selection` rectangle, with some of the circular nodes immediately left and right of it ? That would surely get people in a TikZ-mood, and urge them to help !

Comment: Welcome! What's the issue exactly? Given the existing examples, surely you can manage *part* of this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents)

Comment: thank you @Zarko, I have seen all those questions and I learned a lof from them before I post this.

Comment: @marsupilam, thank you, I'm gonna present what I have done so far in the question above.

Comment: @cfr, I'm gonna present the issue that I have in the question above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
             font = \sffamily,
        shorten > = 1pt,
                > = Stealth,
    node distance = 6mm and 18mm,
      start chain = going below,
 every pin/.style = {pin distance=11mm, pin edge={thin, black, ->}},
    neuron/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1,
                     minimum size=17pt, inner sep=1pt,
                     },
     annot/.style = {text width=6em, align=center},
        BC/.style = {decorate,
                            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=4pt,
                            pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
                            post=moveto, post length=1pt,
                            raise=6mm, mirror},
                            thick,
                            pen colour={red}
                         }
                        ]
% input variables
\foreach \i in {1,...,9}
{
 \ifnum\i=5
    \node[neuron=white,draw=none,on chain]   (in-\i)        {$\vdots$};
 \else
     \ifnum\i<9
        \node[neuron=white,on chain]             (in-\i)    {};
     \else
        \node[neuron=white,draw=none,on chain]   (in-\i)    {$\vdots$};
     \fi
 \fi
}
% Draw the rectangle
\path   let \p1 = ($(in-1.north) - (in-9.south)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y1,\x1)} in
        node (r) [minimum height=\n1,
                  minimum width=9mm, draw, fill=gray!10,
                  below right=0mm and 18 mm of in-1.north]
                  {\rotatebox{90}{Variables selection}};
% input layer neurons
\node[neuron=gray!22,right=of in-1 -| r.east] (I-1) {};
\node[neuron=gray!22,right=of in-3 -| r.east] (I-2) {};
\node[neuron=gray!22,right=of in-6 -| r.east] (I-3) {};
\node[neuron=gray!22,right=of in-7 -| r.east] (I-4) {};
% hiden layer neurons
\node[neuron=gray!44,right=of in-2 -| I-1.east] (H-1) {};
\node[neuron=gray!44,right=of in-5 -| I-1.east] (H-2) {};
\node[neuron=gray!44,right=of in-8 -| I-1.east] (H-3) {};
% out layer neuron
\node[neuron=gray!66,right=of H-2,pin=right:Prévision] (out) {};
% bias nodes
\path (I-1) -| (H-1) node (B1) [pos=0.25,neuron=blue!33] {Bias};
\path (I-1 -| H-1) -| (out) node (B2) [pos=0.25,neuron=blue!33] {Bias};
% Annotations of the layers
\node[annot,above=of in-1]                  {pre-input layer};
\node[annot,above=of I-1]                   {Cauche d'entrée};
\node[annot,above=of I-1.north -| H-1]      {Cauche cachée};
\node[annot,above=of I-1.north -| out]    {Cauche de sortie};

% input labels
\draw[BC] (in-1.north) --
    node[left=11mm,align=right] {xxx\\ yyy\\ zzz} (in-5.south) ;
\draw[BC] (in-6.north) --
    node[left=11mm,align=right] {xxx\\ yyy\\ zzz} (in-9.south);
% nodes connections
% input
\foreach \i in {1,...,4,6,7,8}
    {\draw[->]   (in-\i) -- (in-\i -| r.west);}
\foreach \i in {1,3,6,7}
    {\draw[->]   (in-\i) -- (in-\i -| r.west);}
% input layer
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    {\draw[->]   (I-\i -| r.east) -- (I-\i);}
% hidden layer
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,3}
    \draw[->] (I-\i) edge (H-\j);
% output layer
 \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
    \draw[->] (H-\i) edge (out);
% bias connection.
 \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
    \draw[->,dashed,blue] (B1) edge (H-\i);
    \path[->,dashed,blue] (B2) edge (out);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

i try to reproduce showed image ... but probably in image are missing some element(s), for example text on the input side, etc. this should not be big problem to add to code :)

note, that above *mwe* use recent `tikz` syntax, not obsolete one as it is used in your *mwe*.

Comment: thank you so much @Zarko, I learned a lot from your code, and you are actually a life saver, I have been trying to reproduce that for a long time, and reading about tikz, because I'm still a beginner to it, obviously I'll be drawing a lot of graphs using it in my articles, based on your experience can you please recommend me with a good reference(s) that can give me a good start?

Comment: @Hamid701, instead of saying "thank you" vote for answer and even accept it (by click up-pen and/or check mark on the top left side of answer) :). literature: tikz & pgf manual (it is huge, but for start should be sufficient to read tutorials and then part III), it is part of your `pgf` installation, then examples here on site. for graphs can be handy `pgfplots` package and of course learn-by-doing. when you stuck in it, ask here. happy tex-ing.

Comment: yeah I just did that, but it says that I can't vote yet till I get 15 in reputation, I'm kinda new here :), thank you again I'll follow what you said.