# Creating a rectangle with TikZ using "\draw ... rectangle ..." how can I add relativ labels to edges and corners?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following expression to create a rectangle in TikZ (even so there exist probably a million ways to do it):

```
    \draw[draw=black] (-1.75,-2.5) rectangle ++(5.5,5.5);
```

but using "node" with "midway", "left", "below" ... to add labels at certain areas of the rectangle to name them seem not to work properly so I would like to ask which one the correct way is?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Have a look at the [`pgfmanual`](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) section 72  you will see all node anchors if you want to use a `node` for your base chape. Otherwise your post feels pretty close to this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47704/how-to-establish-node-anchor-like-points-on-a-tikz-rectangle-path-is-there-a

Comment: Thank you very much the pdf you send me did answer my question - it was exactly what I was looking for!